# How to debug that tax_class_id gets overwritten

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, debugging, magento2.2.8

**How can we debug or reproduce the following problem:**

We noticed that the **tax_class_id** of almost all products (96%) get reset to 0 so we mass updated the tax class of the products back to normal. The next day it was reset to 0 again. We started monitoring the attribute value with the following query:

```
select count(*)
from catalog_product_entity_int
where value = 0
  and store_id = 0
  and attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'tax_class_id')
```

Due to the monitoring we figured out that this reset starts at 02:00 AM and continues for 3 hours until almost all products tax class is set to 0.

This behavior occurs on our testing instance as well at the same time but less products are affected (20%).

**What we did so far:**

- Our first thought was that it might be a cronjob that is causing the problem because it occurs every day at the exact same time. So I checked cronjobs running on the server but we only have the Magento cronjobs running and of them no one runs at 02:00 AM.
- We thought it might be due to our import via the rest api but we have a rest logging active and this is not affecting it. On the import the correct **tax_class_id** is pushed to Magento and Magento returns the correct value. As well the import runs later.
- We thought maybe someone acquired access to the admin backend or server so we checked our access logs but there are no abnormalities.
- I checked the Magento logs but I didn't find anything that could lead to a clue.
- I checked our custom modules whether we overwrite the **tax_class_id** somewhere but we don't.

Is there any way to debug this behavior?

Comment: Try to reproduce locally. For this, copy the production database and set the time to 1:59 AM, let crons run etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281693/how-to-debug-that-tax-class-id-gets-overwritten#comment403083_281693) of Alex was a very good Idea and is a way to debug this.

I did set my time to 1:59 AM and let my cron run. At the same time I let a watcher running on my database with the query so I can monitor if the values change.

I noticed that it indeed was a cron responsible for the changes and started to let cron run each one individually with [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) (`n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run cron_name`) to figure out which cron it is specifically (starting with custom crons).

**Tip for debugging a cronjob:**

For easier debugging I dumped the affected table(s) and additionally **cron_schedule** so I can reset them after each run or whenever needed. This is especially useful for a cron that only runs once a day because Magento will mark it as success after running it and it won't run again until next day. To prevent having to set the date every time a day further I recommend the dump.

**What cleared the tax_class_id:**
The cronjob that caused the error was checking every night the products for there `news_from_date` and `news_to_date`attributes. If the current day is between the dates it did set our custom attribute `is_new` to true otherwise to false.
To have a bit better performance only the attributes `news_from_date`, `news_to_date` and `is_new` were loaded with
`$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(['news_from_date', 'news_to_date', 'is_new']);`
Then `is_new` was either set to `true` or `false` but when saving the product `tax_class_id` was set to it's default value (0) because it was not set for the product.

Comment: You might want to shortly elaborate what cleared the tax class id